# Why is my Javascript core not working?

Tags: javascript

The link on the bottom should change when you click one of the radio buttons. I validated the Web page and there are no errors. I proofread my Javascript code and theres nothing wrong with it. Should I use another DOCTYPE?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
function udpateInvestmentLink(urlText, urlValue) {
      document.getElementById('recommendedInvestment').innerHTML = urlText + " (Yahoo! Finance)";
      document.getElementById('recommendedInvestment').href = urlValue;
}
/* ]]> */
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<p>
<input type="radio" name="industry" onclick="updateInvestmentLink('Gold', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=^YH0h714')" />Basic Materials<br />
<input type="radio" name="industry" onclick="updateInvestmentLink('General Electric Industries Ltd.', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=ge')" />Conglomerates<br />
<input type="radio" name="industry" onclick="updateInvestmentLink('Tyson Foods Inc.', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=tsn')" />Consumer Foods<br />
<input type="radio" name="industry" onclick="updateInvestmentLink('Catalyst Health Solutions', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=chsi')" />Financial<br />
<input type="radio" name="industry" onclick="updateInvestmentLink('Genentech Inc.', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=dna')" />Healthcare<br />
<input type="radio" name="industry" onclick="updateInvestmentLink('Toll Brothers', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=tol')" />Industrial Goods<br />
<input type="radio" name="industry" onclick="updateInvestmentLink('Sinclair Broadcast Group Inc.', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?=sbgi')" />Services<br />
<input type="radio" name="industry" onclick="updateInvestmentLink('Verizon Communications Inc.', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=vz')" />Technology<br />
<input type="radio" name="industry" onclick="updateInvestmentLink('Northwest Natural Gas Co.', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=nwn')" />Utilities</p>
</form>
<p><a href="http://finance.yahoo.com/" id="recommendedInvestment">Yahoo! Finance</a></p>
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a spelling mistake `udpateInvestmentLink` and `updateInvestmentLink`, p and d are swapped in the function definition

```
function updateInvestmentLink(urlText, urlValue) {
      document.getElementById('recommendedInvestment').innerHTML = urlText + " (Yahoo! Finance)";
      document.getElementById('recommendedInvestment').href = urlValue;
}
```

Comment: thank you! :O i didnt see that